# Pesquisar entre duas datas na minha base de dados

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Queria saber se poderiam me ajudar a resolver um problema que estou com alguma dificuldade em resolver. O problema é o seguinte:

Eu tenho uma base de dados com uma tabela de valores em que guardo:

- **data**: dateTime
- **valor**: int
- **equipamento**: int (foreign key que vem da tabela equipamentos)

O que pretendo fazer é uma pesquisa em que eu quero que o utilizador preencha duas textbox que recebem um data em cada uma delas e em seguida quero que ao clicar num botão pesquisar que apareça uma gridview com todos os valores dessa tabela mas só as que estiverem no intervalo das datas escolhidas pelo utilizador nas duas textbox.
Estou a trabalhar com ASP.NET com C# e a minha base de dados é o Mysql[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
protected void botaoPequisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {  var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["basedados"].ConnectionString);
   
                DateTime data1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDataInicio.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                DateTime data2 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDataFim.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT idConduta,valor_Lido,data_Leitura FROM valores_conduta WHERE data_Leitura BETWEEN " + data1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " AND " + data2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " AND idConduta=" + ddlHistorico.SelectedValue + "", conn);
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();//definir o objecto dadaset (ds)
                //preencher os dados
                da.Fill(ds);
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) { 

            }
        }
```

Comment: Mario, passe os filtros via `Parameter` !

Comment: Atenção, o DateTime vai de '1000-01-01 00:00:00' até '9999-12-31 23:59:59'

Comment: DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

Answer (score 1):

Faltaram as aspas nos valores das datas, abrir + fechar conexão, além disto, coloquei uma função auxiliar que fiz, para ficar mais limpo o código.

```
protected void botaoPequisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime data1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDataInicio.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            DateTime data2 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDataFim.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            var SQL = "SELECT idConduta,valor_Lido,data_Leitura FROM valores_conduta WHERE data_Leitura BETWEEN '" + data1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " 00:00:00' AND '" + data2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " 23:59:59' AND idConduta=" + ddlHistorico.SelectedValue + "";

            //preencher os dados
            DataTable resultado;
            using(var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["basedados"].ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                resultado = RunSQL(SQL, conn);
                conn.Close();
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = resultado;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) { }
    }

    static public DataTable RunSQL(string sSQL, MySqlConnection MyConnection)
    {
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        using (MySqlDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sSQL, MyConnection))
        {
            try
            {
                #region Executa / Preenche o DT
                //MyDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sSQL, MyConn);
                DT.TableName = "TABELA";
                MyDataAdapter.Fill(DT);
                //'MyDataAdapter.Fill(DS)
                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // by Tony - 26-set-2006 
                // Retorna o SQL e o erro, para facilitar o debug do sistema.
                var newexeption = new Exception(sSQL + " " + ex.Message);
                throw newexeption;
            }
        }

        return DT;
    }
```

- Atenção, o DateTime vai de '1000-01-01 00:00:00' até '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
- TODO: [MySQL Parameters](https://www.google.com.br/?q=MySQL+Parameters+C%23)

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta do Tony, a forma como está implementado o seu código não é uma boa prática, porém acredito que seja algum tipo de estudo ou um POC !

Com isso, você pode enviar os filtros via `Parameter` !

```
protected void botaoPequisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["basedados"].ConnectionString);

    try
    {
        var data1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDataInicio.Text + " 00:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var data2 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDataFim.Text + " 23:59:59", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var id = int.Parse(ddlHistorico.SelectedValue);

        var query = "SELECT idConduta,valor_Lido,data_Leitura FROM valores_conduta WHERE data_Leitura BETWEEN @DataInicio AND @DataFim AND idConduta = @idConduta";

        using (var command = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@DataInicio", data1));
            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@DataFim", data2));
            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@idConduta", id));

            conn.Open();

            using (var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                var ds = new DataSet();

                adapter.Fill(ds);

                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Ola pessoal obrigada pela resposta funcionou perfeitamente, mas surgiu uma duvida, no caso antigo eu queria saber como comparar um data de entre um intervalo de duas datas, como poderei agora comparar duas datas com um intervalo de duas datas?

Comment: Mario, você pode utilizar o *Subtract* do *DateTime*. *data_fim.Subtract(data_ini)* ele vai te retornar um *TimeSpan* !